# exception handling with http client - c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exception, asp.net-web-api

I have the following code. This already exists. What exactly is each block of `catch` doing here. Is this the correct way of handling exceptions on ASP.NET Web API? If not, how can I handle exceptions the correct way.

Note: The `CustomServiceException` in the second `catch` block simply extends the Exception class.

```
        try
        {
            ... I am calling my exteral API here using HttpClient class
        }
        catch(HttpRequestException ex)
        {
           Logger.Error("my error message", ex.Message);                
        }
        catch(CustomServiceException)
        {
            throw;  
        }                
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error("my error message",ex);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what it does is:

- when exception is thrown, it checks if the exception is of `HttpRequestException` or derived type. If that is true, then it logs error message and omits rest of `catch` blocks.
- when the exception is not of `HttpRequestException` or derived type, it checks if it is `CustomServiceException` or derived type. If this is true, then it re-throws the exception (note that `throw` is used here, which preserves original exception data).
- when the exception is not of `HttpRequestException` or `CustomServiceException` (or any of derived types), then we have this 'global' catch block, which will catch any exceptions, log error message and continue working.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is conceptually doing this:

```
try
{
    //... I am calling my exteral API here using HttpClient class
}
catch (HttpRequestException ex)
{
    Logger.Error("my error message", ex.Message);
}
catch (Exception ex) when (ex is not CustomServiceException)
{
    Logger.Error("my error message", ex);
}
```